# Regex to find keywords in URL

Tags: regex, url, dns

I am trying to write a Regex to detect specific keywords in a URL. For example I am looking for the word "update" in a URL and it could be as part of the domain or subdomain like these:

> myupdate.example.com
>   www.my-update.com

I tried this but only get subdomains that start with "update":

```
http\:\/\/\bupdate\b
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
/http:\/\/[^\/]*update/
```